# play MPMoviePlayerController in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, multitasking, mpmovieplayer

I have this code

```
radioPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[radioPlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://217.66.226.47:8024"]];
[radioPlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
[radioPlayer setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
[[radioPlayer view]setHidden:NO];
[radioPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeDefault];
[radioPlayer stop];
[[self view] addSubview:[radioPlayer view]];
```

it doesn't play if the application enter background, What to do ?

Answer (score 2):

In your `plist` file, did you set the `UIBackgroundModes` (`Required background modes`) key to audio? Without this, your application will not play any audio in background.

Here is how to find it:

[image]

More about [iOS Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22).

Comment: can you give me more details ??

Answer (score 0):

> **UIBackgroundModes** (Array - iOS) specifies that the app provides specific background services and must be allowed to continue running while in the background.

Use the **audio** value in your case to your app plays audible content in the background.

For more details: [Apple.Developer - iPhoneOSKeys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22)